# One custom post isn't appearing

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a site with 5 Custom Post Types... and 4 of them are working perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

I have declared this fifth Custom Post Type in exactly the same way I declared all my previous Custom Post Types. It appears in the Admin window, I can create posts, I can even see those posts in the Appearances > Menu screen... but when I visit that section on the site, it displays the 404 from index.php (instead of archive.php -- really odd).

Additionally I have `menu_position` set to `9` (with the others working backwards to 5) and it still appears below Media in the Admin menu... another mystery that might be related. (In the documentation Media is 10.)

[image]

You can see the code that declares the post type here:

```
function custom_post_street() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Street', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Street', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Street' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Street Post' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Street Post' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Street Post' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Street Posts' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Street Post' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Street Posts' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Street Posts found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Street Posts found in the Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Street'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds Street post specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 9,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'street', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_street' );
```

Given the odd placement of the menu in the Admin section I've double checked the the logic works out, and read all the documentation on the [Custom Post Type page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

I've tried emptying all my caches and deactivating my plugins, but nothing has made any difference. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what!

Comment: Try re-saving your permalink settings. It will flush all rewrite rules. It helped me on a 3.x.x version, while I was having the 404 error.

Comment: Agh! That was it! (Although Street still appears below Media, but that's minor.) THANK YOU!

Answer (score -1):

Try to change position : `'menu_position' => 18,`

Comment: Try explaining why changing menu position to 18 will work. This should be in a comment.

Comment: Some time 3rd party plugins take same position .... like as contact from 7. . i solved to change menu position ...